# Label not appearing above UICollectionView cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I've been trying to add an array of labels to my collection view cell but they are not showing up.

```
import UIKit

class HomeMenuViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

var codes = ["NBA","NFL","Girls","Rappers","Celebrities","NFL Teams","Travel","Models","Foodies","Musician","Companies/Brands","Youtube/Viral Stars","Fitness","Snapchat Art","Fashion/Makeup", "MLB Teams"]

var images = [UIImage(named: "title617792344"),UIImage(named: "title236271662"),UIImage(named: "title713937166"),UIImage(named: "title718520594"),UIImage(named: "title205571580"),UIImage(named: "title193064553"),UIImage(named: "title800939906"),UIImage(named: "title987804505"),UIImage(named: "title528311821"),UIImage(named: "title673858816"),UIImage(named: "title543192229"),UIImage(named: "title351533554"),UIImage(named: "title311505831"),UIImage(named: "title579492173-1"), UIImage(named: "title743923696"),UIImage(named: "title544380635")]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 16
}

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "uicvcell", for: indexPath) as! HomeMenuCollectionViewCell

    var image = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView

    image.image = images[indexPath.row]

    var code = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel

    code.text = codes [indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if(indexPath.row == Int("0")){
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "0", sender: nil)
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == Int("1")){
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "1", sender: nil)
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == Int("2")){
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "2", sender: nil)
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == Int("3")){
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "3", sender: nil)
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == Int("4")){
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "4", sender: nil)
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == Int("5")){
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "5", sender: nil)
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == Int("6")){
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "6", sender: nil)
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == Int("7")){
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "7", sender: nil)
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == Int("8")){
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "8", sender: nil)
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == Int("9")){
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "9", sender: nil)
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == Int("10")){
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "10", sender: nil)
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == Int("11")){
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "11", sender: nil)
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == Int("12")){
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "12", sender: nil)
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == Int("13")){
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "13", sender: nil)
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == Int("14")){
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "14", sender: nil)
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == Int("15")){
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "15", sender: nil)
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == Int("16")){
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "16", sender: nil) }
    else if(indexPath.row == Int("17")){
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "17", sender: nil)
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == Int("18")){
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "18", sender: nil)



    }


}
}
```

This is my another file that contains the `IBOutlets`.

import UIKit

```
class HomeMenuCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

   @IBOutlet weak var codes: UILabel!
   @IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!


}
```

I was able to do this in a UICollection View Controller but now that I'm adding this inside a View Controller its not working.

Comment: did you connect the data source and delegate to your view controller

Comment: Did you register the cells with `uicvcell` as the reuse identifier?

Comment: Yes I did do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBOutlet weak var yourCollectionView:UICollectionView!
```

and connect it with your Collection view in Main Storyboard and in

in `ViewDidLoad` methods add the following line

```
self.yourCollectionView.delegate = self
self.yourCollectionView.dataSource = self
```

Comment: Is  [this](http://i.imgur.com/Aa5OmOt.png) the name I would place where you "put yourCollectionView" I tried that and it was getting an error.

Comment: No no `yourCollectionView` is the outlet of your `Collection View` i edit the answer and check

Answer (score 0):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "uicvcell", for: indexPath) as! HomeMenuCollectionViewCell

    //var image = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView

     //cell.image = image[indexPath.row]
    cell.image?.image = UIImage(named: images [indexPath.row]) 

    ///image.image = images[indexPath.row]

    //var code = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel

    //code.text = codes [indexPath.row]
     cell. codes.text! = codes.[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

why do you need to set the tag and complicate the code however this will display the label and you will get thedesired output

Comment: I tried your code and I'm getting the error value of type "HomeMenuCollectionViewCell" has no member "image"

Comment: okay so are you able to see the label now properly with your desired functionality output just comment the image part code and see whether you see the  label or not if you see the label properly then check the following 1). check the outlet of your Uiimage is connected or not and plz let me know if another issues

Comment: I did Check the outlet and it is connected to the collection cell.

Comment: did the label appeared

Comment: yep the labels did show up but now im getting a black blank image http://i.imgur.com/3pK1tWa.png

Comment: Add this code where the image part was commmented          cell.image?.image = UIImage(named: images [indexPath.row])

Comment: plz ask if any other doubt

Comment: which of these do i replace your code with?                                                           "var image = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView"
                                                                                                                                "image.image = images[indexPath.row]"

Comment: i have edited the ans plz refer that and if you found your ans acccept it and upvote it

Comment: I tried your updated answer now I'm get the error "Cannot convert value of type 'UIImage to expected argument type 'String'

Comment: the probelm is with your declaration of the images  declare it  as                var images = ["image name here"]

Comment: I just declared exactly like how you said and the labels are not showing now.

Comment: please can you attach a screenshot

Comment: where should your label should be shownabove the image or below the image and are you sure you cant see them they are not hidden under the image also check the constraints

Comment: The label should be showing above like this http://i.imgur.com/3pK1tWa.png  and the constraints seem to be fine.

Comment: but the gap in between the two images are not set set image to aspect fit

Comment: even setting the image on the collection view cell  to aspect its not showing.